# Can't get Z-index to put an ::after background under the background in the same div. Is this possible?

Tags: css, background, header, z-index, reddit

I'm currently working on a stylesheet for a reddit-style (voat) community. In order to get the background image to keep appearing for the whole width of the browser on larger displays, without distorting the original header background, I tried adding a second image, that'd essentially fill in the rest of the background on the right side, so there was no blank space left.

Since I'm working with only a CSS stylesheet and not any html, I added this second background through use of an ::after element. So I had;

```
#header-container {
    background: url("snip");
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    height: 175%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top: 25%;
    border-color: #000000;
    z-index: 999;
}

#header-container:after {
    background: url("snip");
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    top: 0%;
    left: 1268px;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    border-color: #000000;
    z-index: 1;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Despite the z-index, the ordering didn't change, and the second background added in the latter portion automatically overlayed itself over the first background.

Is there any way to do this without involving html. Or is something in the code just completely wrong preventing it? I also tried offsetting the underlay background (second one) to offset it from the left, so it only covered the portion of background that was missing from the original one (when zooming out), but wasn't completely accurate. Im thinking this is the fault of the **background-size: contain;** line, but not sure.

Sorry for the wall, any help at all appreciated.

Comment: do you need like this http://jsfiddle.net/ytL7zgty/?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but try adding your extra image styles to the `:before` pseudo-element:

```
#header-container:before {
    background: url("snip");
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    top: 0%;
    left: 1268px;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    border-color: #000000;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

... and you can probably get rid of the `z-index` setting in both.